Using a sequence of synonyms for emphasis – is there a special term for that in English?
I stumbled upon the Irish term carnadh comhchiallach recently, defined as ...

A stylistic trick in which words with the same meaning, or almost the same meaning, are put together in a sequence, e.g. No one can force, compel, or browbeat you into a decision.

(I translated this definition from Irish, although the example was in English already.)
Is there a term for this technique in English? I tried Googling synonym piling, synonym accumulation, synonym heaping etc. as those terms seem close to the Irish term. But, as you can imagine, Googling synonym piling, for example, just returns synonyms for the word piling so it's next to impossible to find what I'm actually looking for.
EDIT:
Someone suggested pleonasm earlier and that seems to be on the right track, but the concept of pleonasm appears quite broad, so I was wondering if there is some more specific term. The terms semantic pleonasm, redundancy or prolixity appear to match quite well here, but the examples given in the Wikipedia article on pleonasm don't exactly match my examples, so I would be curious to hear what others think about the terms semantic pleonasm, redundancy, or prolixity in this case. Do they all apply? I think maybe they do.
Here is another example of what I mean:

This project aims to progress, advance, and improve our understanding of cancer cells.


Seems to. Thanks! The Oxford Languages definition I get via Googling 'define pleonasm' seems pretty spot on: "the use of more words than are necessary to convey meaning (e.g. see with one's eyes ), either as a fault of style or for emphasis."

Note that pleonasm simply refers to the property of redundancy, not the rhetorical trope of several synonyms together. eg "a large giant" is a pleonasm. That's not a list of synonyms used for stylistic effect, it's just plain redundant (and often seen as a solecism).

Yes, good point. I felt that the term pleonasm was too general, and that's exactly why I edited the question.

There is a rhetorical device called commoratio. Thought.co explains:

Commoratio is a rhetorical term for dwelling on a point by repeating it several times in different words. Also known as synonymia and communio.

Here is an example from Douglas Adams's The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy

Space is big. You just won't believe how vastly, hugely, mind- bogglingly big it is. I mean, you may think it's a long way down the road to the chemist's, but that's just peanuts to space.


EDIT: Prompted by a comment, I will include here the notorious passage from John Cleese's The Dead Parrot Sketch, to show that commoratio includes cases when the same idea is repeated in different sentences, using different synonyms:

He's passed on! This parrot is no more! He has ceased to be! He's expired and gone to meet his maker! He's a stiff! Bereft of life, he rests in peace! If you hadn't nailed him to the perch he'd be pushing up the daisies! His metabolic processes are now history! He's off the twig! He's kicked the bucket, he's shuffled off his mortal coil, run down the curtain and joined the bleedin' choir invisible! THIS IS AN EX-PARROT!!


Wiktionary defines the term as meaning:

(rhetoric) The use of several synonyms to emphasize something.

A blog called Manner of Speaking, explains it more vividly:

Origin: From the Latin meaning to delay or dwell on a point.
In plain English: Repetition of the same idea using different words.
Effect: Repetition of the idea hammers the point home forcefully.


You learn something new every day. The Monty Python Parrot Sketch example Nordquist mentions is perhaps the most well known. Though not many know the term for the device.

Indeed. I did not want to quote that one, because it is so well-known, but also because each repetition of the same idea is a different sentence. I looked for a passage which resembles more the OP's examples.

But ELU's mission is to tell the whole truth (where it might help visitors not limited to OP).  Commoratio applies to grouped synonyms within, and/or across adjacent, sentences.

+1 for the ex-parrot reminder!

I don't know of a specific word for this that is in common use. That is, that would be recognized by a broad spectrum of English speakers. Linguists may have a technical term for it. I don't know of one but I don't claim to be a professional linguist.
I'd just say, "redundant adjectives" or some similar descriptive phrase.
Note that "pleonasm" is a broader term than what you are describing. It refers to any use of unnecessary extra words, not just redundant adjectives. Like if I say, "tuna fish", the "fish" is redundant. As opposed to what, tuna birds?
I'd also mention along the way that sometimes redundancy is pointless. Other times it is useful for emphasis, and yet other times it helps make the phrase more specific. Like if I said, "The night was dark and black", that's redundant. As opposed to being brightly lit and black? But maybe in context I would say that to emphasize how dark. Like, not just dusk but really midnight dark. And a sentence like, "This is an urgent and serious problem" may not be redundant at all. I might want to make clear that the problem is not just urgent in the sense that we need a solution very quickly, but also that if nothing is done the consequences will be dire. As opposed to a problem that is urgent but not really having terrible consequences.

I believe the technical terms have already been provided in the answer by fev (i.e. commoratio, synonymia, communio), and the point about pleonasm was already made in a comment by Mitch, below my question. I agree that redundancy can sometimes be pointless (i.e. poor style). Other times it might be used for emphasis (i.e. rhetorical effect, persuasion etc.) or humour. I wouldn't personally consider 'urgent and serious problem' to be redundant at all, but it's probably true that many people would just interpret it as 'very important problem', unless they actually stopped to think.
